# Array inside class method

Tags: c#, array

I want to declare string `Array`inside a class and then access it by a method. What I want is to run random inside method and catch the value, but I don't know if I'm doing it right.

```
  namespace Animals
{
    class Animals
    {
         static private string animal1 { set; get; }
         static private string animal2 { set; get; }

         private string randomOfAnimal { set; get; }

        // To run random and get one randomize anmilan I'am runing this
        public string GetAnimal()
        {
            string[] animalList = new string[] { animal1, animal2};
            Random name = new Random();
            randomOfAnimal = animalList[name.Next(0, animalList.Length - 1)];
            return randomOfAnimal;
        }

        public string GetAnimal1()
        {
            return animal1;
        }
        public string Getanimal2()
        {
            return animal2;
        }


        public void PrintAnimals()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Write the first animal name");
            animal1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Write the second animal name");
            animal2 = Console.ReadLine();

        }



    }
}
```

And then I create an object on:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Animals newAnimal = new Animals();
   newAnimal.PrintAnimals(); // to give  a value

   // And then to save randomized animal from class
  string myAnimal = newAnimal.GetAnimal();

}
```

Is this right to do? For some reason it's working but I feel something is wrong.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because the code isn't doing what it should. Please read the documentation of the [`Random.Next()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) especially read about the second parameter and check your code regarding the found information.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think you do not fully understand the concept of `static` members. Until you do, you should avoid using them. Keep it simple.
2. You should avoid creating `GetSomeProperty()` methods, thats what properties are for. In your case, you might want to use [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) instead of properties though.
3. You should not re-create `Random` class if you want randomized results. Create it once and re-use it.

I think your class should probably look like this:

```
class Animals
{
    //check out  Heslacher's comment on Random.Next
    public string RandomAnimal  { get { return _animalList[_random.Next(0, animalList.Length)]; } }

    public string FirstAnimal { get { return _animalList[0]; } }
    public string SecondAnimal { get { return _animalList[1]; } }

    //your original method name is somewhat misleading
    public void ReadAnimals()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write the first animal name");
        _animalList[0] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Write the second animal name");
        _animalList[1] = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private Random _random = new Random();
    private string[] _animalList = new string[2];
}
```